# Can phone use host network when debugging on device via Eclipse/ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have a Android phone connected with host computer with USB cable. ADB runs well and I can debug application on phone. The only problem is that the App requires special network setup which I can reach on host but not mobile. Is there a way to let the device send all network operations through ADB and Host network?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is known as reverse tethering. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sharing your internet connection on your laptop, and connect your phone through it?. Make sure you disable data connection on your phone to assure you are connected through WiFi

Comment: Do you mean that connect the phone to laptop via WIFI AdHoc network and share the LAN? Well I only have WIFI access from laptop (not on phone) and the rom on phone doesn't allow connection to AdHoc networks. Thanks